# How to Customize json result in Mvc Web Api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jsonserializer

In my Web Api application I return both xml and json result. The format is specified in the URL.Based on the url I specified it in Global.asax and return the result. Global.asax is

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
     new QueryStringMapping("format", "json", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")));
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(
        new QueryStringMapping("format", "xml", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml")));
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;//for xml attribute
}
```

Class for serialization is

```
public class ContinentData
{
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
public string Id { get; set; }
[XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("response_item")]
public class ContinentsList
{
[XmlArray("regions")]
[XmlArrayItem("region")]
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "regions")]
public List<ContinentData> Region { get; set; }
public ContinentsList()
{
    Region = new List<ContinentData>();
}
}
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Continents
{
[XmlElement("response_item")]
public ContinentsList Regions { get; set; }
public Continents()
{
    Regions = new ContinentsList();
}
}
```

and i get the xml result, Which is the expected output

```
<response xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<response_item>
 <regions>
  <region>
   <id>AFRICA</id>
   <name>Africa</name>
  </region>
 </response_item>
</response>
```

And the Json result

```
{"Regions":{"regions":[{"id":"AFRICA","name":"Africa"}]}}
```

but I really want the json like

```
[{"regions":[{"id":"AFRICA","name":"Africa"}]}]
```

I return the content in the controller by

```
var regions = _continentService.GetAllContinents();
return Ok(regions);
```

Is there any generalize method for customize the result? How could i do this?

Comment: its not possible as you are having an array of region

Comment: Yes I know.. Currently what i am doing is . In the Controller check the url contains format , if it json ` var regionsArray = new List<object>();
                                    regionsArray.Add(regionsJson.Regions);
                                    return Ok(regionsArray.ToArray());` Is this good or is there any other solution?

Comment: this is good as you are having array...there might be case you are having more region ...at client and you can parse reponse this will give you array of regrion only...so no problem at all

Comment: ok. The only problem is, All result having this condition. code become more lengthy. code redundancy.. that's why

Comment: take look at this project https://github.com/SphtKr/JSONAPI.NET, its known problem